# Truncate Output of Field Php

Tags: php, mysql, truncate

I have a call to the database for this row:

```
echo "{$row['uLName']}";
```

This would output for example say : "`Smith`"

How do I get this call to just output "`S`" or whatever the first letter is of the output using php?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple call to `substr()`:

```
echo substr($row['uLName'],0,1);
```

Or by string index, since a string's characters can be accessed by numeric array index.

```
echo $row['uLName'][0];
```

Comment: Just a small mistake (i think?) - Should be $row['ulName']{0};

Comment: @ShaiMishali No mistake - it's supposed to be `[0]`. It operates like a 2d array in this instance.